# How to add rows into a cursor manually in stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I have a cursor in stored procedure. I want to select some data from a query and insert that data into cursor, then again select some data from another query and append that data into the same cursor.

How can I do this?

Comment: simple cursor or ref_cursor man?

Comment: @Thiyagu - Yes simple cursor, and i want to return that cursor from stored procedure.

Comment: ha ha so no man...for this case u have to use ref_cursor

Answer (score 4):

A cursor is a read-only handle for a SQL statement.  A cursor has no data.  You cannot append data to a cursor.  The only thing you can do with a cursor is fetch the next row.

You can change the SQL statement that is used to open the cursor to `UNION` together the two different SQL statements, i.e.

```
OPEN rc FOR 
  SELECT <<column list>>
    FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT <<column list>>
    FROM table2;

RETURN rc;
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do, what I want

Comment: @NamanGoyal - I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish exactly.  As I said, the statement of the problem doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you can explain the business problem you are trying to solve and what it is about union-ing the results of two queries that fails to solve the problem, we may be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how procedure return values just see this one here 'm using simple ref_cursor

```
create or replace function test_ref() return sys_refcursor is
     temp sys_refcursor;
   begin
     open temp for 'select * from hr.employees ;
     return v_rc;
   end;
   /
```